# Preventing a sticky footer from overlaying a div with background-size: cover; CSS applied

Tags: sticky-footer, css

Client doesn't want his imagery covered by the sticky footer, but wants the background image slideshow to scale with the browser.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply replace

```
background-size: cover;
```

with

```
background-size: contain;
```

There seems to be enough whitespace in the images for the footer not to obscure it in any way by using `contain`. `cover`, on the other hand, stretches the image as much as it can in order to cover the entirety of the `div`, which in turn is stretched to cover the whole page.